# HorizontalListview Not smooth Inside of Listview?

Tags: android, listview, horizontallistview

HI every one am facing one issue in present application,

Issue: HorizontalListview not working smoothly in listview item.

in My app implemented like this

```
 <Listview>
   item1 <Horizontallistview> ..... </Horizontallistview>
   item2 <Horizontallistview> ..... </Horizontallistview>
   item3 <Horizontallistview> ..... </Horizontallistview>
   item4 <Horizontallistview> ..... </Horizontallistview>
   ....
   ....
   ....

 </Listview>
```

Actually am implementing like this but horizontal scroll of each item not working smoothly any one have idea of this give me some ideas.

```
protected void setupViews() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Application.getContext());
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.element_playlist, this, true);
    title = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.title);

    movieplaylistlistview = (HorizontalListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_listview);


    playlistMovieAdapter = new PlaylistMovieAdapter();
    movieplaylistlistview.setAdapter(playlistMovieAdapter);          

}
```

Comment: Check out : https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

Comment: @HareshChhelana Tried already not useful that one.